# Apache Solr integration on shared hosting with cpanel

Tags: database, search

If I do not have any other access to my site's remote server other than file manager via CPanel, is there a way I can get Apache Solr up and running on my Drupal 7 site? The remote host does not provide me with shell access. Does anyone know a tutorial link for this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try [Lucene](http://drupal.org/project/luceneapi)? It doesn't require any shell access and is easy to set up.

Answer (score 3):

No, in this case, you cannot do put Apache Solr on your server.  I just had a client who had the same problem. You have 2 options:

1. Setup a second server that has shell access, and will index you site for you
2. Use someone else's preconfigured Apache Solr already, such as Acquia Search (not free)

Comment: For #1: By *shell access* do you mean SSH? Does that mean I also need to buy another webhosting account as my *second server* instead of using my existing shared hosting account?

Comment: yes SSH.  Yes you'll need a second server,  or find someone that provides Apache Solr service.

Comment: www.opensolr.com is free

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your site to such hosting services, which offer Apache Solr Search together with Drupal like http://drupion.com

Answer (score 1):

Another cheap option is Midwestern Mac's hosted search service (just to throw out another option): there are already many other people using it in tandem with shared hosting to help make search faster and better.

See http://hostedapachesolr.com/

(Disclaimer: I'm the owner of Midwestern Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Do not get hosted on a cPanel server with SOLR. That is a bad idea.

Host your SOLR index(es) with a solr hosting provider that'll give you the solr hostname, port and path, and use it on your cPanel server using the php-solr-client if you're using php.

Such SOLR host would be: http://www.opensolr.com

Answer (score 0):

Some shared hosting companies allow you to get access to shell, but you've to send them a special form (e.g. [HeartInternet](https://www.heartinternet.uk/)).

Alternatively may try to use [PHP Shell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) (if it's allowed) to download solr sources and set-up on your user account. Which is downloading sources via `curl` and run `java -jar start.jar` from your solr example folder.

If this won't work (e.g. they don't have `java`), you have to either use temporary db search ([Search API DB](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_db)), set-up solr on external host or upgrade your hosting into VPS or dedicated one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot install Apache Solr without shell access. You'll need a vps for this. I would recommend [rosehosting](https://www.rosehosting.com). They offer free migration, so they will migrate your website and install Drupal and Solr on your vps.