# Confused about installing Apache Solr

Tags: 7, search

This is pretty embarrassing but I gotta start somewhere, right? This concerns about installing Apache Solr.

I've seen the instructions when trying to install *Apache Solr* and each one starts off with installing Java. I'm confused since I'm using Bluehost for webhosting (http://drupal.org/hosting). Does that mean I need to install Java on my server? There's also the thing about the terminal but I've never seen the terminal in my hosting's Cpanel. Help.

**Edit**: By terminal does that mean *SSH?* Because I can have that enabled in cPanel. It would be nice if there were a simple tutorial for cPanel's users like me. :-)

Comment: Terminal usually refers to a Unix-style command line interface that you run on your computer. Linux and Mac OS X support it natively though Windows requires add-on software such as Cygwin. That said, you would use a terminal window to connect with your server over SSH, which is a secure communications protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/apache-solr-integration-on-shared-hosting-with-cpanel

Answer (score 1):

Yet that's true. If you want to use apachesolr for your own you have to run a java server.

Alternative there are some services which you can pay to host apachesolr for you.
Some examples:

- acquia
- drupalconcept

Comment: I see, so it has to be a java server. So that means I'll need to get a second hosting that has java. Any suggestions? Drupalconcept seems to be non-English.

Comment: You could in theory run them on the same server, solr is fairly advanced , you need lots of content to make it worthwile, are you sure you need it for your solution?

Comment: I have a few big projects in the pipeline and because of that Search has become one of my main priorities. For much smaller sites which Drupal module do you think would be best? Nothing of the Solr caliber.

Comment: If you need a simple search use core search module, for everything else you need some kind of shell access. Oh perhaps http://drupal.org/project/luceneapi could work as well

Comment: For a non-english site i recommended acquia, even i never used it before. There are sure other providers as well, but you can google them for your own.